# How To Convert a JSON Response from Google API for a Timezone Name Into Abbreviated Form?

Tags: javascript, api

Currently calling Google Timezone API and one of the parameters being retrieved is the timeZoneName:

```
var timeZone = (jsonResponseTwo.timeZoneName);
```

This returns the value as "Pacific Standard Time".

What is the best way to convert this into "PST" instead?

This isn't a strong area of mine so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

After checking the Google Timezone API I realized that it also returns timeZoneId as part of the data. Using this, we can get a better approach to the solution:

```
function formatTimezone(timezoneID) {
    let toLocal = new Date();
    toLocal= toLocal.toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: timezoneID, timeZoneName: 'short' });
    let abbreviation = toLocal.split(" ");
    abbreviation = abbreviation[abbreviation.length -1];
    return abbreviation;
}
console.log(formatTimezone("America/Los_Angeles")) //PST
console.log(formatTimezone("America/Anchorage"))  //AKST
```

OLD:

You could split the words and take the first **Letter** of each, put it together and return the new abbreviation.

```
    function formatTimezone(timezone) {
        const words = timezone.split(" ");
        let abbreviation = "";

        for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            abbreviation += words[i][0];
        }
        return abbreviation;
    }
```

Comment: While this will work for the specific example in the OP, it won't work for time zone abbreviations in general.  Alaska Standard Time is AKST, not AST.

Comment: Thanks for the call out, @IanMcLaird. I just modified the code with the info available at the Google API to provide a more accurate result.